# MVC3 inconsistent Json return from ActionResult

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

On a page I have two links

```
<a class="openDialog createButton" data-title="Update Type" href="/Type/Update/4150" title="Update target date"><img alt="Update Target date" src="/Content/Images/arrow_refresh_small.png"></a>
<a class="openDialog createButton" data-title="Change Type" href="/Type/Change/5427" title="Change Type"><img alt="Change Type" src="/Content/Images/arrow_refresh.png"></a>
```

These are bound to the following jQuery function...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $(this).data('title');
        $('#dialog').load(this.href, function () {
            $(this).dialog({
                title: title,
                modal: true,
                width: 600,
                resizable: false
            })
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        //redraw page
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#dialog').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

The URLs point to the following to Actions

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult Change(CorrespondenceLinkVM model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Model state invalid");
            }
            db.UpdateCorrespondenceLink(model.CorrespondenceLink);
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {                
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", genericFunctions.GetLowestError(ex));
            return PartialView(model);
        }
    }
```

The first one (Change) returns a JSON object to the result variable in bindform

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult Update(CorrespondenceTarget model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Model state invalid");
            }
            db.ChangeCorrespondenceTargetDate(model.CorrespondenceTargetID, (DateTime)model.ActualDate);
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", genericFunctions.GetLowestError(ex));
        }
        return PartialView("Update", model);
    }
```

Whereas the second returns the raw JSON with a download prompt, or (if I set the return type as html) straight to the page.

What could cause two functions from the same page (same references) to the same controller (same usings) cause such a different response?

Comment: Have you looked into the Chrome Network debug tab, to see if there any differences in the Request / Response headers?

Comment: Could there be an error in the db.ChangeCorrespondenceTargetDate() function in your Update-action so that you drop in the catch statement and the action returns the PartialView instead of the JSON?

Comment: Dirk - Yes, and there isn't.  In both cases the response is { "success" : true } and the database is updated.

Ceryl, no, error is generated, see above
In the first case BindForm handles it and redraws the page, in the second it tries download it/display it as text in a fresh page.